# Weka: Not Getting Output in Java API

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, weka

I'm implementing a classified filter, that filters based on attributes present in the training data.

```
//implement filter that standardizes via training set
Standardize filter = new Standardize();
filter.setInputFormat(trainingData);

//create a classifier
M5P m5p = new M5P();

//Create a filtered classified, set its filter and classifier
FilteredClassifier fc = new FilteredClassifier();
fc.setFilter(filter);
fc.setClassifier(m5p);

// train and make predictions
fc.buildClassifier(trainingData);
for (int i = 0; i < testingData.numInstances(); i++) {
    double pred = fc.classifyInstance(testingData.instance(i));
    System.out.print("ID: " + testingData.instance(i).value(0));
    System.out.print(", actual: " + testingData.classAttribute().value((int) testingData.instance(i).classValue()));
    System.out.println(", predicted: " + testingData.classAttribute().value((int) pred));
}
```

The code *should* then make some predictions. However, I'm getting blank output.

```
ID: 6.0, actual: , predicted: 
ID: 4.0, actual: , predicted: 
ID: 4.0, actual: , predicted: 
ID: 5.0, actual: , predicted: 
ID: 5.0, actual: , predicted: 
ID: 4.0, actual: , predicted: 
ID: 4.0, actual: , predicted: 
ID: 7.0, actual: , predicted:
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Try checking the values you're passing to the 'value' function `testingData.instance(i).classValue()` to check they have stuff in you expect. If that's wrong, make sure your `trainingData` is actually what you think it is`

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I have some other big issues with my program that I need to check out first. But will definitely keep this part in mind.

Comment: Adam_G - if you have found the answer to the question - post it and accept it please